# How to activate a state on page load for angular ui-sref?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using the following ui-router configuration. So, when the user clicks on a tab, the tab is highlighted correctly as expected. However, no tab is highlighted when the page first loads and the user has to click on a tab for its state to get activated. I would like the home state to be the active tab when the page first loads. How can I achieve this?

```
 angular.module("app", ['app.home', 'app.page1', 'app.page2', 'app.page3'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');

$stateProvider

.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
        'MainContentPlaceHolder': {
            templateUrl: '../Home/_Layout.html'
        }
    }
})

.state('page1', {
    url: '/page1',
    views: {
        'MainContentPlaceHolder': {
            templateUrl: '../Page-1/_Layout.html'
        }
    }
})

.state('page2', {
    url: '/page2',
    views: {
        'MainContentPlaceHolder': {
            templateUrl: '../Page-2/_Layout.html'
        }
    }
})

.state('page3', {
    url: '/page3',
    views: {
        'MainContentPlaceHolder': {
            templateUrl: '../Page-3/_Layout.html'
        }
    }
});
})
```

My HTML markup is:

```
<body>
<section id="NavBar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="page1">Page 1</a></li>
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="page2">Page 2</a></li>
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="page3">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>
    <section id="ContentPlaceHolder" ui-view="MainContentPlaceHolder"></section>
</body>
```

Comment: can you share the code for "when the user clicks on a tab, the tab is highlighted correctly as expected"

Comment: I can only guess in absence of the actual markup. If you are using links in some kind of navigation bar and using [ui-sref](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref)  directive to activate the links you can use the [ui-sref-active](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active) directive to assign a css class to the link that points to the active ui-router state.

Comment: I just added the markup. The thing is when I launch this page the class of all the <li> tags are not defined. It's only when a user clicks on the <li> element the class is set to "active". This is fine. But in addition to this I want the "home" <li> to have class="active" at the beginning when the page is launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I managed to figure out the issue. It was a syntax error at the third line which should change from

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
```

to

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

I had thought that `$urlRouter.otherwise()` takes in the state as parameter. It should in fact be the redirect url.